# SQL: Update GROUP BY to include a value based on max value of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

## Question

How can I add a specific value from a column when using a `GROUP BY` statement and an aggregate function in my query?

## Overview

This is a sample of my table:

```
id  | year | quarter | wage | comp_id | comp_industry |
123 | 2012 | 1       | 1000 | 456     | abc           |
123 | 2012 | 1       | 2000 | 789     | def           |
123 | 2012 | 2       | 1500 | 789     | def           |
456 | 2012 | 1       | 2000 | 321     | ghi           |
456 | 2012 | 2       | 2000 | 321     | ghi           |
```

To calculate the sum of each person's `wage` value by `quarter` and `wage`, I ran the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(wage) AS sum_wage
FROM t1
GROUP BY id, year, quarter, sum_wage;
```

Results in

```
id  | year | quarter | sum_wage | 
123 | 2012 | 1       | 3000     |
123 | 2012 | 2       | 1500     |
456 | 2012 | 1       | 2000     |
456 | 2012 | 2       | 2000     |
```

## Desired Output

I would like to update my query to include the `comp_industry` column where the individual's `wage` is highest for each `quarter` and `year`. I'm unsure where to start so that I only return the industry where folks made the most money for each `quarter` and `year`.

```
id  | year | quarter | sum_wage | comp_industry
123 | 2012 | 1       | 3000     | def
123 | 2012 | 2       | 1500     | def
456 | 2012 | 1       | 2000     | ghi
456 | 2012 | 2       | 2000     | ghi
```

I've taken a look at [Get value based on max of a different column grouped by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585397/get-value-based-on-max-of-a-different-column-grouped-by-another-column) and [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column) but am unsure where to go from there.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your query, from your sample data, not produces that result, what you have in "Results in"

Comment: @OtoShavadze - ah you are right! Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use *window function*  with `SUM` and `ROW_NUMBER`.

Make row number by `id`, `year`, `quarter` columns order by `wage` desc then get `rn = 1`.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   id INT, 
   year INT,
   quarter INT,
   wage INT,
   comp_id INT,
  comp_industry VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (123 , 2012 , 1 , 1000 , 456    ,'abc');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123 , 2012 , 1 , 2000 , 789    ,'def');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123 , 2012 , 2 , 1500 , 789    ,'def');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (456 , 2012 , 1 , 2000 , 321    ,'ghi');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (456 , 2012 , 2 , 2000 , 321    ,'ghi');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id, year,quarter ,sum_wage, comp_industry FROM (
  SELECT *,
           SUM(wage)  OVER (PARTITION BY  id, year, quarter  order by year ) sum_wage,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  id, year, quarter order by wage desc) rn
    FROM T
) t1
where rn = 1;

| id  | year | quarter | sum_wage | comp_industry |
| --- | ---- | ------- | -------- | ------------- |
| 123 | 2012 | 1       | 3000     | def           |
| 123 | 2012 | 2       | 1500     | def           |
| 456 | 2012 | 1       | 2000     | ghi           |
| 456 | 2012 | 2       | 2000     | ghi           |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: thank you for including the DB Fiddle example! This worked out great. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: @CristianE.Nuno No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, does this do the trick for you?

```
SELECT id, 
       year, 
       quarter, 
       comp_industry, 
       SUM(wage)
  FROM (SELECT id, 
               year, 
               quarter,
               comp_industry, 
               wage
          FROM (SELECT TMP.*,
                       RANK() OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY id, 
                                        year, 
                                        quarter
                               ORDER BY wage_sum DESC         
                         ) wage_rnk
                  FROM (SELECT t1.*,
                               SUM(wage) OVER
                                 ( PARTITION BY id, 
                                                year, 
                                                quarter 
                                 ) wage_sum
                        FROM t1
                        GROUP BY id, 
                                 year, 
                                 quarter
                       ) TMP
               ) TMP2
         WHERE wage_rnk = 1
       ) TMP3
 GROUP  
    BY id, 
       year, 
       quarter, 
       comp_industry;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm very new to writing queries so I appreciate you helping me.