# ORACLE: SQL Query to extract last entry date per category

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

By this query

```
select  cust_id, start_time, category from (
select * from events order by category  asc
)where cust_id= '860730'
AND start_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('08/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

I get:

```
    cust_id    start_time      category
    860730  07-NOV-20 07:04:00  1
    860730  07-NOV-20 08:40:36  1
    860730  07-NOV-20 08:49:03  1
    860730  07-NOV-20 08:56:22  1
    860730  07-NOV-20 07:45:53  2
    860730  07-NOV-20 07:56:44  2
    860730  07-NOV-20 08:49:15  2
    860730  07-NOV-20 08:59:37  2
    860730  07-NOV-20 09:10:52  2
    860730  07-NOV-20 11:34:49  3
    860730  07-NOV-20 08:37:10  3
    860730  07-NOV-20 09:00:21  3
    860730  07-NOV-20 13:05:53  3
    860730  07-NOV-20 15:55:34  3
    860730  07-NOV-20 16:07:46  3
    860730  07-NOV-20 16:47:08  4
    860730  07-NOV-20 17:37:27  4
    860730  07-NOV-20 18:59:35  4
```

How can I extract only the most recent records by date per category? To get at the end this result:

```
860730  07-NOV-20 08:56:22  1
860730  07-NOV-20 09:10:52  2
860730  07-NOV-20 16:07:46  3
860730  07-NOV-20 18:59:35  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is to use `row_number()`.  But note the other changes I've made to the query:

```
select cust_id, start_time, category 
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by fme_start_time desc) as seqnum
      from events e
      where cust_id = '860730' and
            fme_start_time >= date '2020-11-07' and
            fme_start_time < date '2020-11-08'
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- Oracle supports date literals.  This is more concise and accurate than converting strings to dates.
- All the `where` conditions can go in the subquery.
- `row_number()` does what you want.
- if `cust_id` is a number -- which I strongly suspect -- drop the single quotes.  Compare numbers to numbers and strings to strings.  Don't mix types.

EDIT:

Actually, given the columns you want, aggregation is simpler:

```
select cust_id, max(start_time), category 
from events e
where cust_id = '860730' and
       fme_start_time >= date '2020-11-07' and
       fme_start_time < date '2020-11-08'
group by cust_id, category;
```

The first version is handy if there are other columns you want.

Comment: SITE_ID     NOT NULL CHAR(6)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32585555/1509264). Please don't answer duplicates but use your close votes instead.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: but if I want to keep the time entirely '07/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss' how can change the query?

Comment: You can use `timestamp` to provide a constant with a time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: instead of date? fme_start_time >= date '2020-11-07' to become 
fme_start_time >= timestamp '2020-11-07' because my database keep the hours

Comment: If your comparison values do not have time components, then `date` is fine for the constants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I mean I want to keep hours and minutes and seconds because the date could be not 00:00:00. I put so to clarify

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it has timestamp. I don't want to truncate the hours/time/minutes... how it will change? the query? thanks ... sorry for this request.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: in fact on my request there is this: AND start_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('08/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') I want to keep that in final query

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError . . . You can keep the query.  I recommend using explicit date and timestamp literals, as this answer proposes.  The absence of a time on a literal in the query has nothing to do with the data in the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but if the time of the range start so? example: 08/11/2020 12:23:44 how can manage it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: if I do     AND fme_start_time >= timestamp '07/11/2020 12:44:15' or     AND fme_start_time >= date'07/11/2020 12:44:15' doesn't work.
Can you please change the query or show me? Using BETWEEN doesn't work aswell

Comment: to_timestamp('07/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')  fixed it. Thank you