# Explanation of KEEP in Oracle FIRST/LAST

Tags: sql, oracle

## Question

Please explain what ***KEEP*** exactly is and the effect of with/without it.

Looking for an explanation but could not find a clear explanation.

[PARTITION BY with and without KEEP in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145952/partition-by-with-and-without-keep-in-oracle/20157109#)

> The real point/power of "KEEP" is when you aggregate and sort on different columns.

[Keep Clause](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2012/09/keep-clause.html)

> Unfortunately, when you start searching for the "keep" clause, you won't find anything in the Oracle documentation (and hopefully because of this blogpost, people will now have a reference). Of course Oracle documents such functions. You only have to know that they are called FIRST and LAST in the SQL Language Reference.

```
# However, you can do even better by just adding three "keep clause" functions to the original query:
SELECT
    ra.relation_id,
    MAX(ra.startdate) startdate,
    MAX(ra.address) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate) address,
    MAX(ra.postal_code) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate) postal_code,
    MAX(ra.city) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate) city
FROM
    relation_addresses ra
WHERE
    ra.startdate <= to_date(:reference_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY
    ra.relation_id
```

Comment: KEEP is just a meaningless keyword (hardcoded, boilerplate text) in the syntax of the `first/last` analytic and aggregate function. It doesn't "do" anything, it is just part of the required syntax. What does "do" something is the aggregation (or analytic function process), grouping by the GROUP BY expressions; the DENSE_RANK FIRST or LAST part of the function; and the aggregate function that comes before the the boilerplate keyword KEEP. Is that the answer you were looking for, or do you need to understand the `first/last` function? If so, start with the documentation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an enhancement request that is somewhat related to KEEP: [Oracle Idea: FIRST() and LAST() aggregate functions](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/idea-first-and-last-aggregate-functions-1055).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Paraphrasing my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157109/1509264):

```sql
MAX(ra.address) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate)
```

The statement can be considered in (roughly) right-to-left order:

- `ORDER BY ra.startdate` means order the rows, within each group, by the `startdate` column of the `ra` aliased table (implicitly using `ASC`ending order); then
- `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST` means give a (consecutive) ranking to those ordered rows within each group (rows with identical values for the ordering columns will be given the same rank) and `KEEP` only those rows that are `LAST` in the ranking (i.e. the rows with the maximum `startdate`); and finally
- `MAX(ra.address)` for the remaining kept rows of each group, return the maximum address.

You are finding the maximum `address` value out of the rows with the maximum (latest) `startdate` for each group.

---

Without the `KEEP` clause:

```sql
MAX(ra.startdate)
```

Means find the maximum (latest) of the `startdate` column for each group.

Comment: Is `MAX(ra.address) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate)` considered to be an analytic/window function or an aggregate function? Also, is `max()` a necessity, or would other functions work like `any_value()`?

Comment: @User1974 Like that, it is an aggregation function; however, it can also be used in analytic functions if you add an `OVER` clause. You can use some other aggregation functions. `ANY_VALUE` is not one you can use. Why don't you try it and find out for yourself [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3nWHRwDs)?

Comment: Thanks. Just for my notes regarding, *"ANY_VALUE is not one you can use."* If I understand correctly, `ANY_VALUE` didn't work in [your fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3nWHRwDs) because you used the Oracle 18c fiddle (my DB is Oracle 18c too). But I think that's just because the  `ANY_VALUE` aggregate function didn't exist in Oracle 18c. However, in newer versions, `ANY_VALUE` does exist, and seems to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/hOjbblcD. But I'm far from an expert, so I might be missing something.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE : Consider the following table
Table name - relation_addresses

relation_id    startdate      address             posta _code     city

1        20-FEB-2019       2,PVR Park            879 776    Tambaram

1        25-MAY-2020    789, CV Raman nagar      877 876    CV Raman nagar

2        18-JAN-2018    97, Paris corner         699 776    Ch main

3        10-MAR-2021    2/ 2678, Park Road       879 776    Bang

4        12-JUN-2019    89, Teck park            638 776    Tech Park

5        03-SEP-2022    309, Paris corner street 673 776    Ch main

5        17-DEC-2020    77, PVR House            690 960    TN

1. ra.relation_id - Gives the respective relation_id . For example 1
2. MAX(ra.startdate) startdate - gives Maximum of startdate  for relation id 1(25-may-2020)
3. MAX(ra.address) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate) address -

   - ORDER BY ra.startdate - Orders the start_date in ascending order (20-FEB-2019, 25-may-2020)
   - DENSE_RANK LAST - gives the last startdate (max of startdate) – (25-may-2020)
   - MAX(ra.address) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate)
     MAX(ra.address) KEEP(25-may-2020) – address for respective start date -
     789, CV Raman nagar
4. MAX(ra.postal_code) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate) postal_code -

   - ORDER BY ra.startdate - Orders the start_date in ascending order (20-FEB-2019, 25-may-2020)
   - DENSE_RANK LAST - gives the last startdate (max of startdate) – (25-may-2020)
   - MAX(ra.postal_code) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate)
     MAX(ra.address) KEEP(25-may-2020) – address for respective start date -
     877 876
5. MAX(ra.city) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate) city -

   - ORDER BY ra.startdate - Orders the start_date in ascending order (20-FEB-2019, 25-may-2020)
   - DENSE_RANK LAST - gives the last startdate (max of startdate) – (25-may-2020)
   - MAX(ra.city) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ra.startdate)
     MAX(ra.address) KEEP(25-may-2020) – address for respective start date -
     CV Raman nagar

GROUP BY ra.relation_id – output is provided based on group by relation_id

Final output will be

relation_id    startdate      address             posta _code     city

1        25-MAY-2020    789, CV Raman nagar      877 876    CV Raman nagar

2        18-JAN-2018    97, Paris corner         699 776    Ch main

3        10-MAR-2021    2/ 2678, Park Road       879 776    Bang

4        12-JUN-2019    89, Teck park            638 776    Tech Park

5        17-DEC-2020    77, PVR House            690 960    TN

Comment: I don't think this adds much to the earlier answers.