# SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's ANY_VALUE(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST ORDER BY ...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

There's a technique in Oracle SQL that can be used to simplify aggregation queries.

Scenario: We've aggregated on a particular column — but we actually want to know information from a different column.

There are a number of ways to achieve that using SQL. I'm looking for a solution that lets me do it in a calculated column -- all within a single SELECT query (no subqueries, joins, WITH, etc.).

Like this:

```
--Oracle
--For a given country, what city has the highest population? (where the country has more than one city)
--Include the city name as a column.
select
    country,
    count(*),
    max(population),
    any_value(city)
        keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)
from
    cities
group by
    country
having
    count(*) > 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y17z2lCD)

As shown above, the following column can bring in the city name, even though the city name isn't in the GROUP BY:

```
 any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)
```

Is there equivalent functionality in SQL Server?

---

Related:

- YouTube - [The KEEP clause will KEEP your SQL queries SIMPLE (Oracle)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlTI_ZUyE0U&t=20s)
- db-oriented.com: [ANY_VALUE and FIRST/LAST (KEEP)](https://db-oriented.com/2021/02/28/any_value-and-first-last-keep/)
- Stack Overflow: [Explanation of KEEP in Oracle FIRST/LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866812/explanation-of-keep-in-oracle-first-last/65868727#65868727)

---

Edit:

I changed `MAX()` to `ANY_VALUE()`, since I think `ANY_VALUE()` is easier to read.

Ties can be broken by adding `, city desc` to the `order by`, making it deterministic:

```
any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc, city desc)
```

Comment: No there is not. You should use CTE or subquery (or some other trick). Even in your Oracle query, I would say that is technically a subquery just with different syntax.

Comment: Is this question some kind of smug oracle commercial? Why do you need to avoid subqueries etc?

Comment: @siggemannen It's not smug. It's a response to a question I got here: [Simplify aggregation queries](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/simplify-oracle-aggregation-queries-using-keep/m-p/1264080/highlight/true#M35293). I want to avoid subqueries etc. to keep queries as short as possible. While having a subquery in this example would be simple enough, when you combine a query like that with other SQL logic in more complex scenarios, the SQL quickly becomes difficult to read. So I want to find ways to make queries as short and simple as possible.

Comment: That's fair i guess, but short != always good. For example some solutions might be short and clever but not well understood or come with caveats, while anyone can understand the classic subquery stuff

Comment: While I understand your motives, as comment before said short is not always good. You should focus first that your queries (code in general) work efficiently, and second that is easy to read. Keeping it short might sometimes align with that, but sometimes it's just going against it. This might be an example of that. You had to explain what that query does, it's not as easy to read for everyone, as CTE with join, and I it's very probably not as efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not implement this.

> I'm looking for a solution that lets me do it in a calculated column
> -- all within a single SELECT query (no subqueries, joins, WITH, etc.)

It's possible but not pretty ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/naKlQFfF)).

Assuming population is a positive integer then you could use the below (See [Solution Based on Concatenation](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/optimizing-top-n-group-queries) for the idea behind this approach)

```
select
    country,
    count(*),
    max(population),
    SUBSTRING(MAX(FORMAT(population, 'D10') + city), 11, 8000)
from
    cities
group by
    country
having
    count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Format d10, that's pretty neat!

Comment: In PostgeSQL, it's possible to aggregate into an array and take the first element: `(array_agg(city order order by population desc))[1]` as a calculated column in the SELECT list. Any idea if the same kind of thing can be done in SQL Server?

Comment: No SQL Server doesn't have arrays - you could do `STRING_AGG(city, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY population)` and then parse the first item out of that but I don't think that is an improvement. The `MAX` approach at least doesn't require any sorting by population as it just has to keep track of a single value per group and doesn't require building a potentially large concatenated string