# SQLite equivalent to Oracle's ANY_VALUE(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST ORDER BY ...)

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

There's a technique in Oracle SQL that can be used to simplify aggregation queries:

*Aggregate on a particular column, but get information from a different column, using a simple calculated column in the SELECT list.*

```
--Oracle
--For each country, what city has the highest population? (where the country has more than one city)
--Include the city name as a column.
select
    country,
    count(*),
    max(population),
    any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)   --<<--
from
    cities
group by
    country
having
    count(*) > 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y17z2lCD)

As shown above, the following column can bring in the city name, even though the city name isn't in the GROUP BY:

```
 any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)
```

---

There are a number of ways to achieve that kind of thing using SQL. I'm looking for a solution in SQLite that lets me do it in a calculated column -- all within a single SELECT query (no subqueries, joins, WITH, etc.).

Question: Is there equivalent functionality to Oracle's `ANY_VALUE(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST ORDER BY ...)` in SQLite?

---

Related:

- YouTube: [The KEEP clause will KEEP your SQL queries SIMPLE (Oracle)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlTI_ZUyE0U&t=20s)
- db-oriented.com: [ANY_VALUE and FIRST/LAST (KEEP)](https://db-oriented.com/2021/02/28/any_value-and-first-last-keep/)
- Stack Overflow: [Explanation of KEEP in Oracle FIRST/LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866812/explanation-of-keep-in-oracle-first-last/65868727#65868727)

---

Edit:

I changed `MAX()` to `ANY_VALUE()`, since I think `ANY_VALUE()` is easier to read.

Ties can be broken by adding `, city desc` to the `order by`, making it deterministic:

```
any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc, city desc)
```

Comment: Why the bounty? Is the existing answer lacking in some way?

Comment: @MartinSmith The existing answer is a good one. With that said, often there are multiple ways of doing things in SQL. I wanted to draw some attention to the question to see if there were any alternatives to the bare columns technique, since bare columns do seem  to have some limitations. From the bare column docs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/806af.png

Comment: Only one of the limitations described in the documentation is important: "If there are two or more min() or max() aggregates in the query, then bare column values will be taken from one of the rows on which one of the aggregates has their minimum or maximum value. The choice of which min() or max() aggregate determines the selection of bare column values is arbitrary...". This is mentioned in my answer. The 1st limitation applies also to Oracle: https://dbfiddle.uk/VrC9_BKm. The 3d limitation about overriding the built-in implementation of the aggregate function is up to you.

Comment: Also, the use of `any_value()` with  `keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)` is pointless. If you want any value in the group then why do you define a sort order with `keep`? You could just do: `any_value(city)`

Comment: @forpas My understanding is: Aggregate functions like `MAX()` and `ANY_VALUE()` are essentially ignored, but are necessary because the column isn't included in the GROUP BY. I believe `any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)` still does what we need it to do. It still gets the city with the highest population. This comment in the YouTube video explains it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BENjS.png

Comment: `MAX()` and `ANY_VALUE()` are not ignored when there are ties in the results of `order by population desc`: https://dbfiddle.uk/1O2r45ds

Comment: @forpas True. In my case, I'm not concerned about what row is used in the case of a tie. And if I was concerned, I think I could add `city desc` to the `order by` in the `KEEP`, like this: `any_value(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc, city desc) as biggest_city`. What do you think?

Comment: (1) Your case is documented: "If only one row ranks as FIRST or LAST, then the aggregate operates on a singleton (nonaggregate) set" in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238. (2) In case of ties after ORDER BY returns then MAX() and ANY_VALUE() are not ignored (3) yes, you can use the ORDER BY clause for the min or max value. But since you have to use an aggregate function for KEEP to work, why would you do it with any_value() which is undocumented (although it works) for use with KEEP? (check previous link)

Comment: I did not say that `ANY_VALUE()` is undocumented. I said that `ANY_VALUE()` is undocumented for use with `KEEP`: "The aggregate_function argument is any one of the MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG, COUNT, VARIANCE, or STDDEV functions." (in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238)

Answer (score 2):

SQLite supports [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) in an aggregate query if one of `MAX()` or `MIN()` is used.

For example, your Oracle query can be written simply like:

```
select
    country,
    count(*),
    max(population),
    city -- this is valid and returns the city with the max population
from
    cities
group by
    country
having
    count(*) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RhPSbkWB).