# How to keep a corresponding value while using an aggregate function in sap hana?

Tags: sql, max, aggregate, common-table-expression, hana

I have a rather complicated query but for the sake of completeness I will post it as it is:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE, COUNT(*) AS count_30_days
    FROM 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE i ON t.DATE >= ADD_DAYS (i.DATE, -30)
                              AND t.DATE <= i.DATE
                              AND t.TYPE = i.TYPE
    GROUP BY 
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE
)
SELECT 
    TYPE, MAX(count_30_days) AS max_incidence
FROM 
    cte
GROUP BY 
    TYPE
```

What is happening here is that I am applying a rolling window to the Date column and I am counting the occurrence in the last 30 days.
From these values I want to have the maximum for each type.

That's what the surrounding statement is for (which is the interesting one).

Of course I have multiple rows before calculating the max value but I want to get the max value of the column count_30_days but also get the corresponding date.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE, COUNT(*) AS count_30_days
    FROM 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE i ON t.DATE >= ADD_DAYS (i.DATE, -30)
                              AND t.DATE <= i.DATE
                              AND t.TYPE = i.TYPE
    GROUP BY 
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE
)
SELECT 
    TYPE, MAX(count_30_days) AS max_incidence, DATE
FROM 
    cte
GROUP BY 
    TYPE, DATE
```

Running this query, I get the following error:

> Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

And it makes sense. I would need something like this:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    ...
)
SELECT 
    TYPE, MAX(count_30_days) AS max_incidence, DATE
FROM 
    cte
GROUP BY 
    TYPE, MAX(DATE) KEEP (dense_rank first order by max_incidence desc)
```

But this throws an error, syntax error near "(". I guess the dense_rank function or something different does not work on hana? Thank you.

How do I get the corresponding `DATE` to the `MAX(count_30_days)` row?

Comment: Is that the proper format for dense_rank? At any rate, I would think that or row_number() function is worth investigating in your solution.

Comment: Yes it's the proper format. There is some issue with the query but I don't get it. I guess the KEEP should be quite universal?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the assumption that *"I guess the KEEP should be quite universal?"* does not match reality.

Turns out, that the `KEEP` syntax belongs to Oracle's [`FIRST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html) and `LAST` functions that are **not** to be confused with the analytical functions `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` described in the SQL standard (and implemented by many DBMS including HANA).

WHile looking into this, I found several entries here in SO:

- [PARTITION BY with and without KEEP in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145952/partition-by-with-and-without-keep-in-oracle/20157109#)
- [Explanation of KEEP in Oracle FIRST/LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866812/explanation-of-keep-in-oracle-first-last)

Where this function is discussed.
In those there is also the link to a very informative blog post [Keep Clause](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2012/09/keep-clause.html) that explains the feature in detail.

Now, SAP HANA does not implement this feature.

To achieve the desired result, one will have to rely on the approach that is often mentioned as the general solution for the "pick the first record from a ordered/ranked set" problem: generating *row numbers* for each entry of the ranked set and select only the records where `row number = 1` for the result:

As the question did not include any test data I had to make up my own, but this example should illustrate the approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE, COUNT(*) AS count_30_days
    FROM 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES i ON t.DATE >= ADD_DAYS (i.DATE, -30)
                              AND t.DATE <= i.DATE
                              AND t.TYPE = i.TYPE
    GROUP BY 
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE
),
ranked_cte AS (
    SELECT TYPE, DATE, MAX(count_30_days)
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY MAX(count_30_days) desc) AS rn
    FROM  cte
    GROUP BY TYPE, DATE

)
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    ranked_cte
WHERE rn =1 
ORDER BY 
    TYPE, date ;
```

As a more side remark: I try to avoid using SQL/HANA keywords like `"TYPE"` or `"DATE"` as identifiers in SQL statements. This may lead to confusion over whether the DB functionality or the data model is referenced. These terms are also very generic and using more specific names for the query at hand typically leads to code that is easier to understand.

This "specific naming" can be extended to the names used for hte CTE's - instead of `cte` and `ranked_cte` one may consider `transaction_counts_30days` and `top_transaction_counts_30days`.

My [presentation](https://www.lbreddemann.org/sap-inside-track-sitmel-full-day-event-in-melbourne/) from the SAP Inside Track Melbourne a few years back covers ***refactoring for readability*** with an extensive example.